# Как растянуть картинку по всему div если в нем несколько картинок

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
    .container{
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        border: solid 1px black; 
    }
    .row{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        vertical-align: top;
        float: left;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .column{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        vertical-align: top;
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
    }
    img
    {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
        object-position: left top;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/611/027/large/evgeny-bubley-teyzin-tunon.jpg?1582973066" class="img">
            <div class="column">
                <img src="https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/0b/91/tyranny_05bf762f.jpeg" class="img">
                <img src="https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/0b/91/tyranny_05bf762f.jpeg" class="img">  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

На данный момент у меня 2 img помещаются через 50% width. Но мне нужно, чтобы все само подстраивалось. То есть я добавляю еще один img и он помещается на один уровень height.

Answer (score 1):

```css
        .container {
            position: absolute;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }

        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            vertical-align: top;
            float: left;
            height: 500px;
        }

        .column {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);

        }

        img {

            width: auto;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: contain;
            object-position: left top;
        }

        .column img {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          
            <img src="https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/611/027/large/evgeny-bubley-teyzin-tunon.jpg?1582973066" class="img">
          
            <div class="column">
              
                <img src="https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/0b/91/tyranny_05bf762f.jpeg" class="img">
                <img src="https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/0b/91/tyranny_05bf762f.jpeg" class="img">  
                <img src="https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/0b/91/tyranny_05bf762f.jpeg" class="img">  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Вам нужны не флексы ,а grid css
конкретно свойство по высоте тоесть строки grid-template-rows,
если нужно такше по ширине сделать то это колонки конкретно grid-template-columns

Comment: Все работает хорошо, но если в column добавить картинки разных соотношений сторон, то все сломается. Скриншот: https://ibb.co/3TD87rP . Я чуть поигрался с width и height но ни к чему это не привело.

Comment: Скиньте ваш код куда нибудь типа codepen или jsfiddle что бы я посмотрел что вы пытаетесь сделать, в гридах не возможно что бы они ломались, это четко описанная сетка CSS

Comment: https://codepen.io/pen/?template=eYdrRvE  Я чуть изменить row img и column img с того момента, но теперь класс column не вписывается в row. Сейчас мне нужно просто вписать column в row. Чтобы не вылезал по нижней границе. P.S. Еще странный баг картинки то огромные, то маленькие. Но даже так они чуть не помещаются в блок row.

Comment: https://codepen.io/richdenis86/pen/LYRrYyr
Попробуйте вот так